# EFCore scaffold database and migrate to another context at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, .net-4.8

Recently I've started to create some PostgreSQL to Mdb/Accdb database converter. I've managed to do it in a bit generic way:

```
public static void TransferData<TSource, TDest>(DbContext sourceContext, DbContext destContext)
    where TSource : class where TDest : class
{
            destContext.Set<TDest>().AddRange(sourceContext.Set<TSource>().Select(_mapper.Map<TDest>));
}
```

Specifying mappings in AutoMapper also in generic way:

```
public void RegisterGenericMapping<TSource, TDest>() => CreateMap<TSource, TDest>();

foreach (var entityName in EntitiesList.DestinationDb)
{
    var sourceType = ReflectionHelper.GetType($"{EntitiesList.sourceNamespace}.{entityName}"); // My helper class to search in all assemblies
    var destType = ReflectionHelper.GetType($"{EntitiesList.destNamespace}.{entityName}");

    typeof(MappingProfile).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == nameof(RegisterGenericMapping))
        .MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, destType).Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Getting the desired entities list this way:

```
public static List<string> DestinationDb = typeof(MsAccessContext).GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.PropertyType.Name == "DbSet`1")
    .Select(x => x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]?.Name).ToList();

public static string sourceNamespace = "DbConverter.NpgsqlSupport.Entities";
public static string destNamespace = "DbConverter.MsAccessSupport.Entities";
```

But the problem is that I still have models in the core. For the source and destination context... It cannot be used without doing database first migration before runtime and paste the same classes to the destination context.

What I want to achieve is to get rid of all model classes and DbSets in contexts' classes:

[image]

During runtime scaffold source database and add DbSets, then basing on the source scaffolded models create destination models and DbSets, apply migration to the destination database and then start the process.

For now my solution works only for one PREPARED database. I need it to be prepared automatically during runtime for every database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use EF for this.  Just use ADO.NET DataReaders and DataTables.  They work perfectly without design-time metadata.

Comment: I'll take a look into ADO.NET. I hope it's not-so-complicated and easy to start.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I'm correct, after my research, but I've found that ADO.NET is just an "interface" which allows an user to open connection to the database (for ex. PostgreSQL) and execure queries and readers?

Comment: And examine the result set metadata, and load results into in-memory DataTables, which have change tracking and support writing to target databases with DataAdapters or bulk insert libraries.

Comment: Okay, then I see that ADO.NET was my first attempt to manage databases, and after some time i came to the conclusion, that it's just less efficient than entity framework. But then I was using only `var conn = NpgsqlConnection.Open(); var cmd = new command(conn)[...]`, passing the query and execute, with or without reader (depending if it's read or insert/delete/update). Is it possible for You to prepare short example of using `DataTables` and `DataAdapters`?

Comment: Or I'm wrong, and I misspell for ex. `Npgsql` library as part of ADO.NET?

Comment: Okay. I've worked a little with ADO.NET It is brilliant and powerfull. I got just one last problem. When I got whole DataSet with all data, type mappings, tables constraints etc. how can I apply a migration of this DataSet to OleDb? When I use `oleDbDataAdapter.Update(dataSet)` i got `Could not find output table 'Roles'.` exception. After breaking this problem I think I'm set. :) Or I have to do it by myself executing right queries in some loop?

Comment: ADO.NET won't create the destination tables for you.  You'll have to examine the DataSet and generate the DDL to create the target tables.

Comment: Thank You. Works like a charm. After some intensive work with ADO.NET now I see it's potential and powerful. I'm really grateful to you for your help.